# CSS box images - layout issues

Tags: css, layout

Im having difficulty with laying out objects using css,

Cant post image due to rep, so image is hosted here....

[image]

The css ive used for each image which is tagged with a div is as the following

```
#compbox img {
  float:left;
   margin:5px;
}
#compwinnerbox img {
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
```

etc etc for each box, although how would i go about making the 3rd box on the bottom row to fill in the gap - so in a sense floating up? Sorry if im not explaining it too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use jQuery Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Or for a CSS approach use `column`

```
.col {
 -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:10px;
-moz-column-gap:10px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-gap:10px; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-gap:2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4gXCs/3/

Answer (score 0):

With CSS and your layout you can't do this given the [specs on floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> 5 - The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the
>   source document.

Comment: Ah ok... any idea on how i would go on about doing it?

Comment: Create a different layout or use JavaScript to correct it. There's a popular plugin that does what you want: http://masonry.desandro.com/